# How to compile a C# DLL from command prompt that references additional assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a C# console application that contains the namespaces `System` and `System.Data`

Additionally, I have added `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`.

When I try to compile from command prompt it shows the error as:

> SqlSmoDiscovery.cs(3,27): error
>   CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Management'
>           does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are
>   you missing
>           an assembly reference?) SqlSmoDiscovery.cs(4,27): error
>   CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Management'
>           does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are
>   you missing
>           an assembly reference?)

But it compiles from Visual Studio.

I am compiling from command prompt to have output as pure C# dll.

My Project in g:

then i navigate to G:\SqlDisc:>  csc /target:library /r Micrsoft.SqlServer.Smo.Dll

SqlSmoDiscovery.cs but it shows the erroe as

error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll' could not be found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `/r` flag to reference additional assemblies from the command line.

```
csc /target:library /r:OtherAssembly.dll Foo.cs
```

Comment: Before that plce the assemblies in the samefolder

Comment: not necessary to place the assemblies in the same folder at compile time.  You can reference the assemblies by full path.  At runtime, The assemblies need to be accessible: generally either in the local dir or in the GAC. Supposing you reference an assembly that is GAC'd, then you can specify it in the csc.exe command as something like c:\Windows\assembly\GAC\DataGridEx\1.0.1.0__852e0362e1c80f34\DataGridEx.dll. At runtime, the GAC'd assembly will be loaded just fine, without copying it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For more info, see [the reference for the csc.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx).